# how to display a date as 2/25/2007 format in javascript, if i have date object

Tags: javascript

how to display a date as 2/25/2007 format in javascript, if i have date object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function formatDate(a) //pass date object
{
  return (a.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + a.getDate() + "/" +  a.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: That's d/m/Y, not m/d/Y, though.

Comment: I assume it's the US way of doing it, m/d/Y

Comment: US dates style is weird. It does my head in. I stick with YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 6):

This would work:

```
[date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDay(), date.getFullYear()].join('/')
```

Comment: date.getMonth() returns from 0-11 so you need to add 1 to it

Answer (score 1):

```
(date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDay() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: getYear() - Returns the year, as a two-digit or a three/four-digit number, depending on the browser. Use getFullYear() instead !! (from w3schools.com)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)! It's a really powerful little library for working with Dates in JavaScript.

Using moment.js...

```
var today = moment(new Date());
today.format("M/D/YYYY");                  // "4/11/2012"
today.format("MMMM D, YYYY h:m A");        // outputs "April 11, 2012 12:44 AM"

// in one line...
moment().format("M/D/YYY");                // "4/11/2012"
moment().format("MMMM D, YYYY h:m A");     // outputs "April 11, 2012 12:49 AM"
```

Another example...

```
var a = moment([2012, 2, 12, 15, 25, 50, 125]);
a.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Monday, March 12th 2012, 3:25:50 pm"
a.format("ddd, hA");                       // "Mon, 3PM"
```

---

Also, its worth mentioning to checkout [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). I think the two libraries complement each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<input type="button" value="display" onclick="display()" />
<input type="text" id="dis" /><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
function display(){
var x="You have clicked";
var d=new Date();
var date=d.getDate();
var month=d.getMonth();
month++;
var year=d.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("dis").value=date+"/"+month+"/"+year;
}
</script>
```

For more details please visit http://informativejavascript.blogspot.nl/2012/12/date-display.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option for all users (internationally) is `toLocaleDateString`.

```
var date = new Date("2007-02-25 01:00:00"); // for some reason a time is needed
var dateString = date.toLocaleDateString();
console.log(dateString); // outputs 2/25/2007
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString