# How to format this date + time got from JavaScript? (+jsFiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to display a date as 2/25/2007 format in javascript, if i have date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536516/how-to-display-a-date-as-2-25-2007-format-in-javascript-if-i-have-date-object)

How can I format the following date+time to this one     **2012-07-24 17:00** ?

http://jsfiddle.net/28Tgz/1/

I am trying to make use of

```
formatDate('yy-mm-dd HH:ii', now));
```

without luck.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var foo = jQuery('#foo');

function updateTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    foo.val(now.toString());        
}

updateTime();
setInterval(updateTime, 5000); // 5 * 1000 miliseconds
});
```

this return me 
**Wed Jul 25 2012 17:14:02 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)**

Comment: [10 ways to format time and date using JavaScript](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)

Comment: [Formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/1331430)

Comment: I've put some effort to answer your question, I don't have much time to be dawdling on SO for much longer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get it done:

```
function updateTime() {
    var now = new Date(),
        d = [];

    d[0] = now.getFullYear().toString(),
    d[1] = now.getMonth()+1, //months are 0-based
    d[2] = now.getDate(),
    d[3] = now.getHours(),
    d[4] = now.getMinutes();

    //doing YY manually as getYear() is deprecated
    //remove the next line if you want YYYY instead of YY
    d[0] = d[0].substring(d[0].length-2); //not using substr(-2) as it doesn't work in IE

    //leading zeroes
    for (var i=1; i<=4; i++)
        if (d[i] < 10) d[i] = '0' + d[i];

    foo.val(d[0] + '-' + d[1] + '-' + d[2] + ' ' + d[3] + ':' + d[4]);
}
```

### **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/28Tgz/61/)**

## *Reference*

[MDN Javascript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/)
[10 ways to format time and date using JavaScript](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)
[Formatting a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728/1331430)

Comment: Thank you for this. I find it strange that I can't get it working into my page though...

Comment: Did you copy the whole function?

Comment: Yes entirely. Is it because I have other jQuery scripts too ?

Comment: Very unlikely, seeing as my script uses local variables only. Well, give a try to this other [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/28Tgz/58/) even though it's pretty much the same but with `.push` instead of creating the indexes. I'd say to check your javascript console for errors (F12 in Chrome and FF with Firebug installed, or Ctrl+Shift+K for Firefox's native console), now if that still doesn't work then your best bet is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Found my error. I have accepted your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have just noticed that the date is wrong, as in here http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/28Tgz/57/ the date is 03 instead of 25

Comment: Oh wow, good catch. Gimme a second to review it.

Comment: Alright, fixed. I accidentally typed the day of week instead of day of the month. Just swap `now.getDay()` by `now.getDate()` -- already fixed in the code and fiddle. Yeah about time to call it a night. `:P`

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var foo = jQuery('#foo');

    function updateTime() {
        var now = new Date();
        var date = now.getFullYear() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getDate() + ' ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes(); 
        foo.val(date);        
    }

    updateTime();
    setInterval(updateTime, 5000); // 5 * 1000 miliseconds
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qh9uN/)

You can pad `0` if date/month/hour/minutes is less than 10.

Comment: How to add the `0` to allow only double minutes ? ( 08 insted of 8 )

Comment: I leave that as your assignment. Pass each entity to function and if its less than 10 return the `0 + value`

Comment: Well, if I knew, I wouldn't ask you to...

Comment: I am sorry but I have to recall my acceptance of this answer until it's completed.

Comment: I am sorry but I cant help you. SO is to help , its not 'do my homework'. I helped you because I know you dont know the answer. But I expect you to do some work on it.

Comment: and copy from example :)

Comment: exactly. I am sorry that I had to recall my acceptance though.