# Javascript date format for a date

Tags: javascript, datetime

How do I format a date in Javascript to something e.g. 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z'?

This `date.toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z');` never work out for me :/

Any idea?

======

I solved my own which I rewrote like this:

```
var parseDate = function(date) {
    var m = /^(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d) UTC$/.exec(date);
    var tzOffset = new Date(+m[1], +m[2] - 1, +m[3], +m[4], +m[5], +m[6]).getTimezoneOffset();

    return new Date(+m[1], +m[2] - 1, +m[3], +m[4], +m[5] - tzOffset, +m[6]);
}

var formatDateTime = function(data) {
    var utcDate = parseDate(data);

    var theMonth = utcDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var myMonth = ((theMonth < 10) ? "0" : "") + theMonth.toString();

    var theDate = utcDate.getDate();
    var myDate = ((theDate < 10) ? "0" : "") + theDate.toString();

    var theHour = utcDate.getHours();
    var myHour = ((theHour < 10) ? "0" : "") + theHour.toString();

    var theMinute = utcDate.getMinutes(); 
    var myMinute = ((theMinute < 10) ? "0" : "") + theMinute.toString();

    var theSecond = utcDate.getSeconds(); 
    mySecond = ((theSecond < 10) ? "0" : "") + theSecond.toString();

    var theTimezone = new Date().toString();
    var myTimezone = theTimezone.indexOf('(') > -1 ? 
            theTimezone.match(/\([^\)]+\)/)[0].match(/[A-Z]/g).join('') : 
            theTimezone.match(/[A-Z]{3,4}/)[0];

    if (myTimezone == "GMT" && /(GMT\W*\d{4})/.test(theTimezone)) {
        myTimezone = RegExp.$1;
    }

    if (myTimezone == "UTC" && /(UTC\W*\d{4})/.test(theTimezone)) {
        myTimezone = RegExp.$1;
    }

    var dateString = utcDate.getFullYear() + "-" + 
                     myMonth + "-" +
                     myDate + " " +
                     myHour + ":" +
                     myMinute + ":" +
                     mySecond + " " +
                     myTimezone;

    return dateString;
}
```

and I get: 2012-11-15 22:08:08 MPST :) PERFECT!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display a date as 2/25/2007 format in javascript, if i have date object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536516/how-to-display-a-date-as-2-25-2007-format-in-javascript-if-i-have-date-object)

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate but it's the same problem and you should figure it out from there.

Comment: i read that one, some used external scripts. i want something pure with function.

Comment: Only one answer provided an external library. Others use pure JavaScript.

Comment: i try not to do substring or string.format stuffs :/

Comment: Why the bloody hell not O.o?

Comment: well, then no choice, stick the old fashion.

Comment: You should add your solution as an *answer* rather than edit your question (that way it can be upvoted by others and you can accept it).

Answer (score 1):

```
function formatDate(dateObject) //pass date object
{
  return (dateObject.getFullYear() + "-" + (dateObject.getMonth() + 1)) + "-" + dateObject.getDate()   ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use this lib to make your life much easier:](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

```
var formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss');
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML= formattedDate;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4duy3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we have three methods and you have to combine the strings for yourself:

> getDate(): Returns the date
>
> getMonth(): Returns the month
>
> getFullYear(): Returns the year

Example:

> var d = new Date();
>
> ```
> var curr_date = d.getDate();
>
> var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
> var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
> document.write(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year); </script>
> ```

for more details look at [10 steps to format date and time](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3) and also [check this](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/)